How to make react-select move horizontally when it goes off screen
I found that the component has a menuPlacement property, but it adjusts the select position only when going beyond the screen vertically, I did not find a horizontal analogue
I tried using Popper.js and passing it as a component to Menu, but it doesn't do anything.
const CustomMenu = (props) => {
  const referenceElement = props.selectProps?.selectProps?.controlRef;
  const popperElement = useRef(null);

  const { styles, attributes } = usePopper(referenceElement?.controlRef, popperElement.current, {
    placement: 'bottom-start',
    modifiers: [
      {
        name: 'preventOverflow',
        options: {
          boundary: document.body,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'flip',
        options: {
          fallbackPlacements: ['bottom-start', 'bottom-end', 'top-start', 'top-end'],
        },
      },
    ],
  });

  return (
    <div ref={popperElement} style={{ ...styles.popper, zIndex: 9999 }} {...attributes.popper}>
      Popper
      <components.Menu {...props} />
    </div>
  );
};

const controlRef = useRef(null);
<ReactSelect 
ref={controlRef}
components={{
          Menu: CustomMenu
}}
selectProps={{ controlRef: controlRef?.current }}
/>

